# reading data from text file and add it into array

Tags: c

I tried to read the data from a text file and add it to an array. However, it raises an error ["Warning:" assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast]. I declared fp is a variable of FILE, and already open text file with read-only mode.

```
char arrRequest[100];
char strRow[10];
int i = 0;


.....................

void request(){
  for (;;){
      fgets(strRow, 10, (FILE *)fp); 
      i = i + 1;
      arrRequest[i] = strRow;  // it raises an error here
      printf("value of %d is %s:\n", i, arrRequest[i]);
  }
}
```

Could you please tell me why it happens?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your intention by "add it to an array" ? - do you mean you want to add character strings (strRow) into a single char array (arrRequest) ?

Comment: Aside: what is `fp` if you are having to make the cast `(FILE *)fp`?

Comment: An equality assignment will usually be the wrong choice, even if you have an array of string pointers, because they will all point to the same (most recent) entry. Here you need `strcpy` but you can only store one string. Perhaps you need `char arrRequest[100][10];`

Comment: Post a [mcve] to improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you declared:

```
char arrRequest[100];
char strRow[10];
```

But in for loop:

```
arrRequest[i] = strRow;
```

It means you assign a character to an array of character. So it raises an error here.

If you want to copy a string, you should use`strcpy` function. You can declare an array of pointer or 2D array as the comment above:

```
char arrRequest[100][10]
// using strcpy
strcpy(arrRequest[i], strRow);
```

Or

```
char * arrRequest[100]
// allocate for each arrRequest element
arrRequest[i] = malloc(strlen(strRow)*sizeof(char) + 1);
if (!arrRequest[i])
   // Handle error
```

OT, you should use `while` loop to stop reading the file if there is nothing still to read. You can use `for` loop as you used in your code, but have to stop reading until you meet `EOF`. Do not need to cast `fp` if you declare `FILE *fp` before.

```
while(fgets(strRow, 10, fp);)
```

Comment: I want to copy a string from reading a text file into string array in request function. After I use your recommendation 
````
arrRequest[i] = malloc(strlen(strRow)*sizeof(char) + 1); 
````
it builds successful, but I can not print out its value by printf to check.

Could you please give me any ideas about this mistake? I also re-post my little program in this thread including all functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, I use another from you and now it works. Thanks for your help